# ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file error

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, ld

I am new to operating system programming and I am reading a book which gives a simple example of  kernel as follows:

```
main() {
   char *video_memory = 0xb8000;
   *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

To compile this file which is called kernel.c, I use MinGW under Windows 7 as follows:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
```

This creates the object file kernel.o. However, following command does not work.

```
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary
```

I receive the following error:

```
ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file 'kernel.bin'
```

I cannot solve the problem. Please help me.

Thank you

After helps of Ross, I succeded to jump to kernel offset. However, I cannot call C function from Kernel_entry.asm. Moreover, when I remove the C function from my kernel.bin and change the code as seen below, Three weird chars are shown on the screen.

Kernel_entry.asm is as follows:

```
[bits 32]
;[extern _start]
mov ebx, MSG_KERNEL_ENTRY
call print_string_pm
;call _start
jmp $

%include "print_string_pm.asm"

MSG_KERNEL_ENTRY db "Kernel entry is invoked", 0
```

bootsec.asm is as follows:

```
[org 0x7c00]

KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp
mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE
call print_string
call load_kernel
call switch_to_pm

jmp $

%include "print_string.asm"
%include "disk_load.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"
%include "print_string_pm.asm"
%include "switch_to_pm.asm"
%include "clear_screen.asm"
[bits 16]
load_kernel:
mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL
call print_string

mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
mov dh, 15
mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
call disk_load

ret


[bits 32]

BEGIN_PM:
;call clear_screen
mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
call print_string_pm
call KERNEL_OFFSET
jmp $

BOOT_DRIVE  db 0      
MSG_REAL_MODE   db "Started in 16-Bit Real Mode", 0
MSG_PROT_MODE   db "Successfully switched to 32-Bit Protected Mode", 0 
MSG_LOAD_KERNEL db "Loading Kernel into memory", 0  

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

All messages are shown correctly but the last one in the Kernel_entry.asm is shown as three weird chars. I don't understand what happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to is change the name of you function. If you call it `main` the MinGW version of GCC will insert a call to `__main` to do initialization. For example:

```
start() {
   char *video_memory = 0xb8000;
   *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

This means you'll also have to edit `kernel_entry.asm` accordingly:

```
[bits 32]
[extern _start]
call _start
jmp $
```

Next compile and assemble the two files as you did before, and link it with these commands:

```
ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
objcopy -O binary -j .text  kernel.tmp kernel.bin
```

The first command links the objects as a PECOFF executable, and then the second command converts it to a binary. Now combine the binary with the boot loader:

```
copy /b boot_sect.bin+kernel.bin os-image
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works when I call kernel offset from assembler code. But this time I cannot merge assembler kernel entry code with c code. I tried following:

Comment: Thank you very much. This works when I call kernel offset from assembler code. But this time I cannot merge assembler kernel entry code with c code. I tried following: nasm kernel_entry.asm -f win -o kernel_entry.o and then ld -r -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o lastly with objcopy command I create kernel.bin. Everything fine but there is no X on the screen. I receive no error message. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you combine `boot_sect.bin` with `kernel.bin`?

Comment: Yes, becasue I work with a windows machine, I used "type" command: type bootsec.bin kernel.bin empty.bin(full of 0 bytes to convince bochs it is a disk) > os-image.img. I put some messages in boot sector code. All messages appear but it doesn't put X on the screen. I don't understand.

Comment: Don't use `type`, it doesn't handle binary files correctly. You'll also need to modify `kernel_entry.asm` because you changed `main` to `start`. I've updated my answer with these instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much Ross. I did everything you suggested. But it doesn't work. I even removed the C function and add a message to the kernel_entry. But the message is not shown correctly. I updated my question. Would you please check it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've made a change to my answer. Instead of using `-r` linker option, which links everything into one object file, I've used `-T NUL` which tells the linker not to use a linker script. The intent of both of these options is to remove some extra junk that the linker script will add. The `-r` option however was causing the fixups to be applied incorrectly. Note that this may not be the end o your problems. The approach taken by the book your following is very fragile.

Comment: Thank you! this time it works. However, I would like to ask you two more questions: (1) Why this code is fragile? Would you advise me any other source that I can read? (2) Do you have any idea why pure kernel.bin (from which C function was removed) put 3 weird chars on the screen? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The approach the author is taken is dependent on the compiler and linker doing certain things and not doing certain other things, but compiler and linker make no promises to do or not do these things. This is why you had to call `main` something else. I don't know of any other source that would cover this topic in tutorial manner like this. The version linked with `-r` would have passed the wrong address to `print_string_asm` because the relocations weren't being performed correctly. Using `-T NUL` instead results in the correct relocation being applied to the address.

Comment: I realise this is very old now but by using ```-j .text``` do you not lose all other sections from the object and hence any included strings etc.? Is there any reason for doing this rather than including them all?

Comment: @JamJar00 Yes, you lose all the other sections, but the original poster didn't have any other sections. At least not until he changed the question. As I mentioned in a previous comment this whole thing is very fragile. You can just copy everything but then you end up with a much bigger file because it ends up containing a couple of useless 4K aligned sections (`.rdata$zzz` and `.eh_frame`). A better solution would be to write a custom linker script (ie. not `NUL`) that puts everything (except the junk) in `.text`.

Comment: Hello, inspired of the Poster's Text there, I have create successfully a binary under Microsoft Windows 11 Professional 64-Bit with the help of the MinGw32/64-Bit ToolChain's. You can a working Copy at my Git Account: [paule32](https://github.com/paule32/JustFunOS_win32/releases/tag/Release). You only need to install MinGw with the given installer, download, depack the Project files, and open the Mingw, where You type **make**, and the Makefile can be used to build a binary image. I only have test the Compile, not the Run, yet. But lets rock ... :-)