# GCC create flat binary with correctly linked data section

Tags: c, gcc, binary, objcopy

I try to create a flat binary file with `gcc` using `objcopy`.
My C code looks like:

```
char* str = "Hello world!";
printString(str,12);
```

When I create my binary with

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -c cfile.c -o cfile.o
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -o comfile.o afile.o cfile.o
C:\MinGW\bin\objcopy -O binary comfile.o kernel.bin
```

The code section (`.text`) is linked correct, but the data section (`.rdata`) is just put behind my code section and not linked with my code section. If I access anything in the data section, it will load something from 0x0x401000 instead from the correct location and will crash.

Is there a way to solve this?

PS: Working C code is:

```
char* str = "Hello world!"-0x401000;
printString(str,12);
```

Comment: What does "flat binary" mean?

Comment: @unwind a file I can directly load to the memory and execute without linking or any other chages.

Comment: Write a linker script where you specify the base address and size for each section?

Comment: @Michael How can I do this? I never worked with linker scripts.

Comment: this link: http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.10/ld_3.html will tell you everything you want to know (and a lot more) on the rules for writing linker scripts.

Comment: How about this answer ? [ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25129926/2565527)